# Circulating Supply of an SPL Token

Tags: token, spl, supply

I'm seeking out the simplest method to determine the circulating supply of an SPL token. This should be available to query via HTTPS.

My first thought is to use:

```
getTokenSupply - locked tokens = circ supply
```

Would this be best suited for Web3 JavaScript API?

Comment: the post is written in a very opinionated manner, detracting from its value.  please consider rewording

Answer (score 2):

You can easily get the supply of an SPL token with `getTokenSupply` RPC method.

```
curl <RPC_ENDPOINT> -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {"jsonrpc":"2.0", "id":1, "method":"getTokenSupply", "params": [<TOKEN_ADDRESS>]}
'
```

More info: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettokensupply

Answer (score 0):

There is no one concept of "circulating supply".  It is up to the token issuer as to how they circulate the asset.

For instance backed stablecoins typically over-mint their supply, retaining the excess in one or more accounts controlled by their deposit/redemption infrastructure